# How to initialize a GLfloat array?

Tags: c++, c

I want to put some lighting into a project i created, but i get the following compiler error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float' to 'GLfloat []'
```

What is the problem?

```
GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);


GLfloat lightColor0[] = (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
GLfloat lightPos0[] = (4.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 1.0f);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightPos0);

GLfloat lightColor1[] = (0.5f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
GLfloat lightPos1[] = (-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightPos1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have used wrong array initialization syntax. You may not use () to list array elements.
Syntax is { list_of_the_elements }

So change () to {}

```
GLfloat lightColor0[] = (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
```

to

```
GLfloat lightColor0[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
GLfloat lightColor0[] = (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
```

You need curly braces there `{...}` not parentheses `(...)`. The way you wrote it, the compiler sees a buch of floating point literals, with comma operators inbetween. The last expression of a comma series becomes the value of what's inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `{ ... }`, not `( ... )` to initialize your array of floats.

Note that you are doing it right in the first line:

```
GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
```

But wrong in the lines below:

```
GLfloat lightColor0[] = (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example shown you have parentheses around the data for `lightColor0` and onwards.  I think you meant curly braces as used for `ambientColor`.